# Windows Firewall prevents File and Printer sharing from working

Tags: file-sharing, windows-firewall

I have a domain-joined machine (Win2K8R2) that I'm using at work, and I'd like to copy some files to my personal machine (Win7) that is currently not on the domain.

If Windows Firewall is enabled, I can't see my personal machine at all from my work machine.  If I turn it off, I can ping it and navigate (via \\[machine]) to it and do what I need to do.

What I'd like to do is not need to disable Windows Firewall in this situation.  On my personal machine I have my corporate network set to the "Work" profile, and "File and Printer sharing" is enabled for Private networks.  It looks like it should work, but it's not.

What's the best way to troubleshoot this?  I'd like to be able to pinpoint why this is not working.  In case it helps, the corporate network uses IPSec.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using either Windows 7 or Vista, since you did not specify.  When you open up the firewall settings, go to "allow a program." Then make sure the file and printing sharing is turned on.

Comment: I've done this, it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Can you navigate to it by IP address if the firewall is on?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, with Windows7,  the ports for File Sharing are already allowed through the windows firewall.   Because you joined a domain, it appears that the domain administrator has limited or set your firewall rules to disallow these ports.

Once a system joins a domain, it is forever locked into the rules of that domain server.